# Jquery ui sortable hold and drag for mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery UI sortable list. I am trying to make it work on mobile devices. I used the touch punch workaround. In order to scroll I have to deactivate the sortable function, I have done that and on taphold of a list element activate the sortable function. That is working ok, but the problem is that I want that while on taphold to allow the sorting of the element. Now it only works like this: taphold the element (taphold stops) and then I have to again tap it in order to sort.

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="list-group" id="wrapper">
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 1</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 2</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 3</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 4</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 5</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 6</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 7</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 8</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 9</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 10</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 11</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 12</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 13</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 14</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 15</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 16</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 17</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 18</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 19</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 20</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 21</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 22</li>
 <li class="list-group-item">Block 23</li>
</ul>
```

JS Code:

```
$('#wrapper li').on('taphold', function(event, ui) {
    $( "#wrapper li" ).removeClass('selected');
    $( "#wrapper" ).sortable({disabled:false});
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$( "#wrapper" ).sortable({disabled:true,containment: "parent"});

$( "#wrapper" ).on( "sortupdate", function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#wrapper" ).sortable({disabled:true});
} );
```

Here is a jsfiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/3cygah12/) of the example.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: you need to implement touch events  -- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml -- you can find plenty of examples on the net, however because you are working on the y axis i.e up/down you will need to set a timer of at least one second before you set (disabled:false) otherwise scrolling and dragging items may be both instantaneous and you may get a problem

Comment: i already did that,the problem is that i cant call event for drag start on taphold or touchstart or anything.I can enable sortable but i can drag the element only when the function finishes.So it works like this taphold(touchstart)->enables sortable ->taphold(touchstart) ends->then i can drag.

Comment: yeah i know how it functions, i tried it on my mobile when i saw your Q.  take a look at an answer i gave some time ago for dragging items on the X axis to see what i mean about JS touch events. you can try reversing it to work only on Y axis and see if can do the job  --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966181/jquery-touchswipe-event-on-element-prevents-scroll/29969575#29969575

Comment: I get what you are saying but the real solution to this problem would be to somehow call the native jquery ui event for sorting on the current element that is being touched but there is not documentation about it and i cant seem to replicate it.

Comment: i created a demo for u as a possible solution that its best of both worlds. Using a scrollstart function you disable the table and a click to enable the drag and drop. This is the kind of functionality a user would expect i think on mobile. check it out and if you like this approach ill put it as an answer -- https://jsfiddle.net/hwbhLaqf/

Comment: this is not it,i need a solution where the user immediately can drag the element and in your example he has to click it first to enable dragging and after that he can drag it.But thanks for help anyway.

Comment: try hammer js -- http://hammerjs.github.io/ -- . good luck

Comment: can't you bind sortable true on touchend ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to do it.

I modified a part of touch punch( http://touchpunch.furf.com/ ) code  like this to bind touchstart to taphold -

```
mouseProto._mouseInit = function () {

var self = this;

// Delegate the touch handlers to the widget's element
self.element
    .bind('taphold', $.proxy(self, '_touchStart'))   // IMPORTANT!MOD FOR TAPHOLD TO START SORTABLE
    .bind('touchmove', $.proxy(self, '_touchMove'))
    .bind('touchend', $.proxy(self, '_touchEnd'));

// Call the original $.ui.mouse init method
_mouseInit.call(self);
};
```

And also used https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events . It works now!

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm using `jQuery UI Touch Punch 0.2.3` version and replace code as you have given. And also I have included before touch punch `touch-mouse-events` from your given github link. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, i have the same issue as you had, but i dont fully understand how you used the jQuery Touch Events. Could you modify your fiddle or post a new one with your changes? +1

Comment: Maybe you can address this issue? https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/issues/243

Comment: @TheWandererr I updated the OP's fiddle to get this working (on my touchscreen laptop and iPhone): https://jsfiddle.net/3cygah12/8/

Answer (score 10):

I addressed the same issue with this tiny plugin:

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Add this library to your to your scripts.

Another way to do it, is to download the whole mobile jquery library ([here](https://jquerymobile.com/)) and work like this

```
$('#yourSelector').on('touchstart mousedown', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var touch = event.touches[0];
 if(touch){
   //Do some stuff
 }
 else {
  //Do some other stuff
 }
});
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with //Do some stuff?

Comment: Depends what you want from your program to do.