# jQuery UI Sortable -- Div is not draggable when the page is scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-touch-punch

In advance thanks for taking a look at my question.

I am creating a website where i have a list of divs which are sortable on the Y-axis using [jQuery UIs](https://jqueryui.com/) sortable.
 Since i want this to run on mobile devices using touch i had to add a little hack to make sure that jQuery UI is usable( since it currently does not support touch events.).
 The hack is called jQuery UI touch punch.
 Website: [jQuery UI touch punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/).
 GitHub: [jQuery UI touch punch](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/).

> Now comes my problem. Sometimes the list gets so big that the website
>   will get scrollable and when the site is scrollable i cannot properly
>   drag the items since when i try to drag a div it just scrolls the
>   page. The only way i can drag it is when i double tap the item and then
>   drag it.
>  But this is really not what i want since it is really
>   tedious to use and unnatural.

The question now is, is there a way to disable the scrolling when trying to drag one of the items from the draggable set. I tried adding `overflow-y: hidden` on tap or adding `touch-action : none`. Unfortunately this didn't seem to work.

> ***SUMMARY***
> **What i have:** I can currently drag and sort a List of Divs
>   with a touch device using jQuery UI and jquery UI touch punch.
>  **The
>   Problem:** The list will get so big that the site is scrollable which
>   disables the dragging with a single tap i need to double tap
>   to drag the item.
> **What i want:** I want to be able to drag the
>   items(without double tapping) even when i have a scrollbar.

How could i realize such behaviour / with what should i start? Any tips and solutions are appreciated.

Last but not least here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u67sun5d/1/).

**EDIT:**

I am using:
IE 11
jQuery version 1.11.1
jQuery-ui version 1.11.4

Comment: Maybe something with `containment`, like `containment: "window"`. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: @Twisty unfortunately this is not working

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027761/jquery-ui-sortable-hold-and-drag-for-mobile

Comment: Surely you're not saying you want to disable scrolling completely? How do you think the user should access things that are off the bottom of the screen?

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u67sun5d/1/) working fine with drag items with single click. I have checked in android device.

Answer (score 8):

Try either replacing (recommended) touch punch library (or in addition to it) with the following JS snippet and calling `init()` function on `$(document).ready();`:

- Note you can comment styles on `#wrapper`, they were set just for overflow testing.
- Ideally you would leave some space out of draggable items in order to scroll without undesired dragging.

Snippet below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    init();
    $("#myContainer").sortable({
        //your code
    })
});

function touchHandler(event) {
    var touch = event.changedTouches[0];

    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent({
            touchstart: "mousedown",
            touchmove: "mousemove",
            touchend: "mouseup"
        }[event.type], true, true, window, 1,
        touch.screenX, touch.screenY,
        touch.clientX, touch.clientY, false,
        false, false, false, 0, null);

    touch.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
}

function init() {
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
}
```

**[---> Fiddle with snippet replacing touch punch <---](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/u67sun5d/6/)**

**[---> Fiddle with snippet + touch punch <---](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/u67sun5d/5/)**

(Both tested in mobile safari & chrome, drag is achieved on 1st tap)

Comment: Hey thank you for your solution and sorry for the late response. It seems to work in chrome but i get following Error when i touch the screen: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'initMouseEvent' on 'MouseEvent': parameter 4 is not of type Window`

Comment: Not getting the error in the Internet Explorer 11 which i have to use, but in which your solution is not working. Unfortunately i didnt mention that in my question. Any idea on how to make it work in the Internet Explorer. It seems that the scroll has a higher priority or something. I gonna give you the bounty nonetheless when no other answers is provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot . This solution did work for me. One update - I had to remove preventDefault form TouchHandler because it was creating other complexity with clearing canvas and all.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these lines to your touch punch library js file.

```
function simulateMouseEvent(event, simulatedType) {   
// Ignore multi-touch events


> if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
>         return;
>     }
> 
>     var touch = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],
>         simulatedEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
> 
>     if ($(touch.target).is("select")) {
>         event.stopPropagation();
>     } else {
>         event.preventDefault();
>     }
`
```

Include the above lines.